# How to increase password length while creating account on a drupal website?

Tags: 7

I'm using Drupal 7, is there any configuration on drupal to make users choose passwords with more than `10` characters (for example) when they're creating accounts ? For now, any user can choose username, and a password can contain only one letter and it's not safe.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds as if you need the [Password Policy](https://www.drupal.org/project/password_policy) module.

From the project page:

> This module provides a way to enforce restrictions on user passwords by defining password policies.
>   A password policy can be defined with a set of constraints which must be met before a user password change will be accepted. Each constraint has a parameter allowing for the minimum number of valid conditions which must be met before the constraint is satisfied.